# where is settings of application if I use NAnt

Tags: winforms, nant

I would like to ask, if I use NAnt to build my winform application and then copy the folder of release with exe file to the users' PC, how could I find the file of settings of application on users' PC?
Let me make an example, in settings.settings I add an settings of application, then i write some value. Then I use NAnt to build the project to geneare the folder of release with exe file. Then I cpoy the folder of release to the users' PC. Then I want to modify this setting of application. I'd like to ask, where should I modify?
Thank you very much,

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? NAnt does not create any application settings files, as such I am not sure how the location of such settings would be specific to NAnt.

Comment: hi, thank you very much for your kindness reply.  Let me make an example, in settings.settings I add an settings of application, then i write some value. Then I use NAnt to build the project to geneare the folder of release with exe file. Then I cpoy the folder of release to the users' PC. Then I want to modify this setting of application. I'd like to ask, where should I modify?   Thank you very much again

Comment: Are you saying you want to modify a file on a remote machine using Nant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are deploying this exe to a user-PC and want to modify the config settings.

- To deploy it remotely you can use PSExec
- To edit it remotely, you can use xmlpoke to get the config settings and update it. Make sure the location is shared and the Nant script can modify the file. Example \\user-PS\application_name\app.config